# how to get the object by array of object and arraylist based on condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, object

I have array of object arrobj and arrlist prgList,

I need to fetch the name from the arrobj based on the programs in the list using javascript.

If the program prg exists in the arrobj , fetch and should display as show in expectd output

tried

```
var lists=[]
var result =arrobj.find(e=> e.prg.includes(prgList) ? lists.push(e))); // bit stuck
```

```
var arrobj = [
  {id:1, name: "user1", prg: ["onex", "twox", "threex"]},
  {id:2, name: "user2", prg: ["onex", "threex"]},
  {id:3, name: "user3", prg: ["twox", "threex"]}
]

var prgList = ["onex", "twox", "threex"]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  onex: ["user1", "user2"],
  twox: ["user1", "user3"],
  threex: ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
}
```

Comment: Why does `twox` in the expected output not contain `user1`?

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for reply, yes should be there, updated output

Comment: Find stops execution when it hits true. Why are you using it here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var arrobj=[
  {id:1, name: "user1", prg: ["onex", "twox", "threex"]},
  {id:2, name: "user2", prg: ["onex", "threex"]},
  {id:3, name: "user3", prg: ["twox", "threex"]}
];

var prgList =["onex", "twox", "threex"];

var result = prgList.reduce((a, key) => {
  const users = arrobj.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.prg.includes(key) ? [...acc, curr.name] : acc), []);
  return { ...a, [key]: users };
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

This reduces the `prgList` array to an object that has as keys all its values.
At each iteration, `arrobj` is reduced to an array of `users` that contain that specific value from `prgList` in the `prg` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do for instance as following:

```js
const input = [
  {id:1, name: "user1", prg: ["onex", "twox", "threex"]},
  {id:2, name: "user2", prg: ["onex", "threex"]},
  {id:3, name: "user3", prg: ["twox", "threex"]}
]

const prgList = ["onex", "twox", "threex"]

const output = Object.fromEntries(prgList.map(key => [
    key, 
    input.filter(x => x.prg.includes(key)).map(x => x.name)
    ]))
 
 console.log(output);
```

From each element in `prgList` create a `[key, value]` pair, where the element is the `key` and the `value` is the list of users, which contain the key, mapped to their names only. Then use `Object.fromEntries` to create an object from these `[key,value]` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here as:

```js
const arrobj = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "user1",
        prg: ["onex", "twox", "threex"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "user2",
        prg: ["onex", "threex"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "user3",
        prg: ["twox", "threex"]
    }
]
const prgList = ["onex", "twox", "threex"]

const result = prgList.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const props = arrobj.reduce((acc, prgs) => prgs.prg.includes(curr) ? [...acc, prgs.name]: [...acc], [])
    return {...acc, [curr]: props};
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

You can easily get the result using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as:

```js
const arrobj = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "user1",
    prg: ["onex", "twox", "threex"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "user2",
    prg: ["onex", "threex"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "user3",
    prg: ["twox", "threex"]
  }
]
const prgList = ["onex", "twox", "threex"]

const result = Object.fromEntries(prgList.map((prg => [prg, arrobj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const isUserExist = curr.prg.some(o => o === prg);
  return isUserExist ? [...acc, curr.name] : acc;
}, [])])))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you are already using `reduce` why not immediately reduce to an object instead of an array?

Comment: @derpirscher You're right. Added that solution also. Thanks